# How to inject css code in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement enable dark mode in my chrome extension. I have been able to do the options page and it's saving correctly but I don't know how to make it work in such a way that when a user check the enable dark mode option, it would show dark mode.

I have been researching on solution to this in the last 48 hours but didn't get to relate them to the problem i'm experiencing.

Here are some of the codes I have written:

Note: Currently, I don't know what to put in my content_script.js

Manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "*://*.facebook.com/*",     
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "options_page": "options/options.html",

    "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": [
                "*://*.facebook.com/messages/*",
                "https://www.messenger.com/*"
            ],
            "js": ["/assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js", 
     "/assets/js/content_script.js"],
            "css": ["/assets/css/content_script.css"]

        }]
```

options.html

```
   <html>
   <head><title>My Options</title></head>
   <body>
    <h1>My Options</h1>
    <h3>Enable night mode</h3>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="night-mode">
    </label>    
    <div id="status"></div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>


    <script src="options.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/js/simplebar.js"></script>       
        <script src="../assets/js/util.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
        <script src="../assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

options.js

```
    var enableNightMode = document.getElementById('night-mode').checked;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
    enableNightMode: enableNightMode
    }, function() {
      // Update status to let user know options were saved.
      //console.log('Value is set to ' + enableNightMode);

      var status = document.getElementById('status');
      status.textContent = 'Settings Saved.';
      setTimeout(function() {
        status.textContent = '';
      }, 3750);
          });
}

    // Restores checkbox state using the preferences
    // stored in chrome.storage.
    function restore_options() {
    // Use default value color = 'red' and likesColor = true.
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
    enableNightMode: true
    }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('night-mode').checked = items.enableNightMode;
    //document.getElementById('like').checked = items.likesColor;
    });
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
    document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
    save_chatsilo_options);
```

background.js

```
   function updatePage(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(
        {
            enableNightMode: true
        },
        function(settings) {
            if (true === settings.enableNightMode) {                
                //document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                //console.log(document.body.style.backgroundColor);

                //chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, { file: "../js/css/darkmode.css" });
                chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, { file: "../css/darkmode.css" });

            } else {
                //document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                //console.log(document.body.style.backgroundColor);
            }
        }
    );
}
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(updatePage);
updatePage();
```

darkmode.css

```
    background-color: #365899 !important;
    }

    ._3i_m ._2her {
    background-color: #365899 !important;
    color: #365899 !important;
}
```

I want user to be able to enable the dark mode and then the css (darmkmode.css) would be adding to the page and the effect would take place.

Please, note:

darkmode.css is located in assets/css/..
background.js is located in assets/js/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs API so you should move insertCSS call into an extension script (like the background script).

Comment: @wOxxOm, I just moved it now and it didn't work. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I have edited the code and here is the content of the background.js

Comment: You need to make that code run when a tab is created or navigated. For example by using chrome.tabs.onUpdated or chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted. Alternatively you can make a simple content script that sends a message to the background script's onMessage listener where you'll invoke updatePage().